# How can I test that an expression is a member of a field extension of $Q$

Tags: algebra

Are there functions in Mathematica that I can use to define a field extension of $Q$? I want to be able to check if an element $a \in Q(\sqrt2)$.

So far I've tried to bypass this with with expressions like

```
MinimalPolynomial[a, x, Extension -> Sqrt[2]]
```

and then verifying the degree of the minimal polynomial, but it looks like this doesn't work very well (it insisted on saying that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2$ over $Q(\sqrt2)$ was $x^2-2$)

Any ideas?

Comment: `ToNumberField[Sqrt[3] + 1, Sqrt[2]]`?

Comment: What i need is a little bit different. Basically i am programming and i need something that returns "True" or "False" to insert this in a conditional.             Something like this:                                                
`If["what_im_lookingfor, do this, do other thing]`                                         So i don't need a generic message and an useless output

Comment: `FreeQ[Quiet@ ToNumberField[Sqrt[3] + 1, Sqrt[2]], ToNumberField]`?

Comment: That's it thank you